# I want to update the model I created. However, I want to do this through the id of the model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to update my model according to the id number. how can I do that?
I can update the model but I want to do this via id
and another problem i have is i want only the creator to be able to update the model

### Model.py

```
    class Advertise(models.Model):
        owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="ilan başlığı")
        description = models.TextField(max_length=500, verbose_name="ilan açıklaması")
        price = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="Fiyat")
        square_meter = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="Metrekaresi")
        number_of_rooms = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=NumberOfRoomsChoices.CHOICES, 
        verbose_name="Oda sayısı")
        building_age = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=NumberOfBuildingAgeChoices.CHOICES, 
        verbose_name="Bina Yaşı")
        floor = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=NumberOfFloorChoices.FLOOR_CHOICES, 
        verbose_name="Bulunduğu Kat")
```

### serializer##

```
class AdvertiseMainSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Advertise
        fields = '__all__'
```

### view.py##

```
class UpdateAdvertiseData(UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = AdvertiseMainSerializer
    queryset = Advertise.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

### urls.py##

```
url(r'^UpdateAdvertiseData/(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$', UpdateAdvertiseData.as_view()),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself again.

### When I add the following function to the view model, we can only update the models belonging to the logged in user.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return self.queryset.model.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

### and we select the user who is automatically logged in with the following function.##

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

### view.py##

```
class UpdateAdvertiseData(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = AdvertiseMainSerializer
    queryset = Advertise.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.model.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```